# Javascript. I am trying to use .findIndex() but I get the following message: TypeError: a is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have ‘array magazine’ and ‘string ransomNote’. And want to access an element of the array based on an element from the string.

This is what I am trying: magazine.findIndex(ransomNote[i])

```
var canConstruct = function(ransomNote, magazine){
    magazine = magazine.split('');
    //console.log(magazine);

    for(let i = 0; i < ransomNote.length; i++){
        if (magazine.includes(ransomNote[i])){
            element_to_erase = magazine.findIndex(ransomNote[i]);
            magazine = magazine.splice(element_to_erase , 1);
            //console.log(magazine);
            continue;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};

console.log(canConstruct('aa', 'aab'));
```

Comment: Did you maybe mean to use `.indexOf()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findIndex` takes a function as an argument, and you are passing it a string

you need to do

```
  magazine.findIndex((magazineString) => magazineString === ransomNote[i])
```

Or just use `indexOf` as its pointed in the comments, and probably validate if that returns something other than `-1` (indexOf) or `undefined` (findIndex) in either case.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting the input string `magazine` to an array, you can use `magazine.search` directly -

```js
const removeCharAt = (str = 0, pos = 0) =>
  str.substr(0, pos) + str.substr(pos + 1)

const canConstruct = (ransomNote = "", magazine = "") => {
  for (const char of ransomNote) {
    const pos = magazine.search(char)
    if (pos >= 0)
      magazine = removeCharAt(magazine)
    else
      return false
  }
  return true
}



console.log(canConstruct('aa', 'aab'))
// true

console.log(canConstruct('az', 'aab'))
// false

console.log(canConstruct('stay inside', 'diet coke on sale this sunday'))
// true
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another issue. While splice, u don't need to reassign. Splice modify the same array.

> You can simplify using [array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```js
var canConstruct = function (ransomNote, magazine) {
  magazine = magazine.split("");
  return ransomNote.split("").every((rChar) => {
    const rIndex = magazine.indexOf(rChar);
    if (rIndex !== -1) {
      magazine.splice(rIndex, 1);
      return true;
    }
  });
};

console.log(canConstruct("aa", "aab"));
console.log(canConstruct("az", "aab"));
```